# Using maximum of forecasted values to forecast maximum

Tags: forecasting

I am using an algortihm to generate a daily sales Forecast and have concluded that the Forecast is, for pratical purposes, of good enough quality ("low" wMAPE).

In general, and without further information, is it possible to conclude something about using this Forecast to predict the maximum future sales over a time interval?

That is, if
$$
F_{1}, ..., F_{n}
$$are presumed to be good enough to forecast actual sales values$$
S_{1}, ..., S_{n}
$$

Can we state something about using 
$$\max (F_{1}, ..., F_{n})$$
to forecast
$$\max (S_{1}, ..., S_{n})   ?$$

Comment: I'd recommend you consider using the sum of your upper prediction interval for F1,...,Fn (if you have one). If you do not have a prediction interval automatically generated by your model/software then there are ways you can create yourself. I say consider because it depends on what the purpose is of knowing the maximum. This approach would yield a much larger # than what you proposed.